# I keep getting a line of character as my output for my sum of all years WHY?

Tags: java

Everything that ive done so far is correct, but once i get down to my last print statement i keep getting a string of characters as my answer when i should be getting the sum of all the salaries for the  entire array.  PLEASE HELP ! 
my output is 
Total money made by person at row 1 is 118943
The total salaries of all individuals is [[I@1540e19d

```
public class SummerStats
{
   private int [][] salaries;

   public SummerStats(int numPeople, int numYears)
   {
      //initialize array
      salaries = new int[numPeople][numYears];

      java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
      //fill array
      for(int i=0; i<numPeople; i++)
      {
          for(int j=0; j<numYears; j++)
          {
            salaries[i][j] = r.nextInt(100000);
          } 
      }
   }

   public int [][] getSalaries()
   {
      return salaries;
   }

   public int getMostMoneyOverYears()
   {
      int [] tmp = new int[salaries[0].length];
      int k = 0;

      for(int i=0; i<salaries.length; i++)
      {
           for(int j=0; j<salaries[i].length; j++)
           {
            tmp[k] += salaries[i][j]; 
           }
           k++;
      }    

      return getMax(tmp);
   }

   private int getMax(int [] arry)
   {
      int sal1=0;
      int idx=-1;
      for(int i=0; i<arry.length; i++)
      {
          if(sal1 <arry[i])
          {
            sal1= arry[i];
            idx = i;
          }
      }

      return idx;
   } 

   public int getHighestSalary()
   {
      //find the highest salary in a single year and return of the index
      int [][] tmp = new int [salaries.length][2]; //stores salary (row) and the index (col) from the     salaries [][]
      int max = 0;
      int idxtmp = -1;

      int p=0;

      for(int i=0; i<salaries.length; i++)
      {
         for(int j=0; j<salaries[i].length; j++)
         {
           if(max < salaries[i][j])
           { 
             max = salaries[i][j];         
             idxtmp = j;
           }               

         }
         //add max value and its corresponding index to tmp
         tmp[p][0] = max;
         tmp[p][1] = idxtmp;

         p++;
   } 

  //now that we have the max for each person (row) compare salaries in each row         
  //reset values
  max = 0;
  idxtmp = -1;
  for(int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++)
  {
     if(max < tmp[i][0])
     {
        max = tmp[i][0];  //this is the max salary
        idxtmp = tmp[i][1]; //this is the index of the salary from the salaries[][]
     }
  }   

  return idxtmp;
  }

   public int getTotalSalary (int person)
   {

    int totalSalary = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<salaries[person].length; i++)
    {
     totalSalary+=salaries[person][i];
    }



  return totalSalary;
  }
  //get total of all salaries
   public int getAllSalaries()
   {
     int sum = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<salaries.length; i++)
     {
       for(int j=0; j < salaries[i].length; j++)
       {
        sum += salaries[i][j];
       }
     }   

     return sum;
   }
}



import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestSummerStats
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      SummerStats ssObj = new SummerStats(2, 3);
      int [][] sal = ssObj.getSalaries();

      for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
      {
         for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
         {
            System.out.println("Salary at " + i + " " + j + " is $" + sal[i][j]);
         }
      }

      //keep my output looking clean
      System.out.println();

  System.out.println("Index of the big baller: " + ssObj.getMostMoneyOverYears());

  //keep my output looking clean
  System.out.println();

  System.out.println("Index of the year with the highest salary: " + ssObj.getHighestSalary());

  //keep my output looking clean
  System.out.println();

  //promt the user to enter the person that you want the salary for
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the person you want to know the salary for.");
  int person = scan.nextInt();

  //keep my code clean 
  System.out.println();

  //print out the amount of money made by the specified person 
  System.out.println("Total money made by person at row " + person + " is " + ssObj.getTotalSalary(person));

  //sum the entire salaries
  System.out.println("The total salaries of all individuals is " + ssObj.getSalaries());



   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `getSalaries()` is declared and defined thusly:

```
public int [][] getSalaries() {
  return salaries;
}
```

It is defined to return a two dimensional array, and the result you're seeing is the default `toString()` returned from such a beast. To get an actual number, your method should return a number, perhaps a double or an int, your choice, and inside the method body, you should iterate through your 2-D array summing up all the salaries.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the text in the last line, you should change the method call in the last line from `ssObj.getSalaries()` to `ssObj.getAllSalaries()`.

The "string of characters" you are getting is what happens when you convert an array to a `String` (either implicitly by concatenating with another string or explicitly by calling `toString()` on the array).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function getSalaries() which returns an array. You should be calling ssObj.getAllSalaries().

The string you're getting is probably a reference to the salaries array object.

Comment: so yeah i felt stuppid after seeing that, but me being curious i would like to know how it still ran?

Comment: The run-time figures out you're trying to output a string because of the first operand being a string "The total salaries of all individuals is ". It then helps you out by converting whatever comes next into a string.

In this instance, it converts the array to a string by doing the equivalent of ssObj.getSalaries().ToString() automagically.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @SVMRAJESH - How is this not an answer to the question?

Comment: @TedHopp That's called a robo-reviewer.